# Android STFP library

Tags: android, sftp

I want to use SFTP in my Android project. Does Android already have an
SFTP library, or do I have to implement it?

Answer (score 5):

I use [andFTP](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andftp/index.html) for sftp transfers but it's not open source.

You can check [connectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/). There is an issue about [sftp transfers](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/issues/detail?id=100).

Comment: Hi Macarse
Thnk you your reply.
I went through connectbolt SSH open source client on android.
Now i want to ask if i can integrate FTP and connectbolt SSH to form my SFTP?? How much feasible it would be considering that i dont know much of internals of SSH. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think they are going to add it, but it's not there yet. Post a comment on the issue and ask them out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html) is a commercial Java library that works on Android and supports SFTP (as well as FTP and FTPS).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.54'
```

Proguard (I do keep it public and ignore warnings. Easy solution, overkill. I choose not to mess with it here). If you know correct solution - let me know.

```
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.*
-keep class * extends com.jcraft.jsch.KeyExchange
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.**
-keep class com.jcraft.jzlib.**
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.jce.*
-keep class com.jcraft.jzlib.ZStream
-keep class com.jcraft.jsch.Compression
-keep class org.ietf.jgss.*
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.jcraft.jsch.**
```

code:

```
// add correct exception-handling; remember to close connection in all cases
public void doUpload(String host, String user, String password, String folder, int port, File file){
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session.setPassword(password);

    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    //Don't do it on Production -- makes it MITM-vulnerable
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setTimeout(5000);
    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
    session.connect();

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    String home = channelSftp.getHome();
    if (folder == null || folder.length() == 0 || "/".equals(folder)) {
        folder = home;
    } else {
        File file = new File(new File(home), folder);
        folder = file.getPath();
    }
    channelSftp.cd(folder);

    try (BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()))) {
        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(buffIn, progressListener, file.length());
        channelSftp.put(progressInput, file.getName());
    }

    channelSftp.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}
```