# Android Java SFTP / SSH

Tags: android, security, ssh, sftp

I'm making a small android app for one of my secure servers (which has a random root password generated every 5 mins with the first few characters known to the user, the random part of the password is stored in a .txt file on the server under another user which is the only one that can view this random part of the password.) I need my Android app to connect to this secret user over SFTP or SSH (secure) to retrive the random password to display it to the user so they are able to login to the system.

This is like my own cheap version of two factor authentication. I'm new to Android development but i can't find any SFTP libraries for this connection. Can you help?

Thanks Dave

Comment: have you considered key-based authentication? (may not be relevant at all, just a thought)

Comment: This is not a secure solution.

Comment: I don't care if its not ultra secure, my question was really, how do i do sftp on andorid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SFTP in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251247/sftp-in-android)