# Android SFTP Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, ssh, sftp

I want to be able to download a file in my android app using SFTP / SSH not FTP. Is this possible and how?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: see this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server

Comment: possible duplicate of [SFTP in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251247/sftp-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Try JTA: http://javassh.org/space/start

Also JSch: http://seancode.blogspot.com/2008/02/jsch-scp-file-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

[edtFTPj/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpjssl/overview.html) is a Java library supporting SFTP (and FTPS) that works on Android. Disclosure: I'm one of the authors.