# Android Client to Send files using SFTP

Tags: android, file, ftp, sftp

All,
      
I am new to FTP and SFTP Protocols.I need to send files to SFTP Server from an android client..

1)Does android has SFTP support in-built in SDK ?

2)If not, how do i accomplish the same in Android??

3)Any useful Link or Lib or App will help me

Thanks in advance

NITZ

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in SFTP support in Android SDK, but there exists a fair number of Java classes for SSH/SFTP capable of doing FTP and SFTP including our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-secure-file-transfer.php) (Java edition), [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (SFTP only, no FTP/FTPS) and some others mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251247/sftp-in-android).

NOTE: [SFTP and FTP are completely different protocols](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftp-ftps.net/ftps-vs-sftp.php).

Comment: Mayevski 'EldoS thanks for your reply..Is SecureBlackbox free??..open source classes would be helpfull!!!!

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder I had hard time trying to find anything open-source with Android support.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder Seems that JSch can be used on Android. I've updated my answer.